# Look up value bsed on substr

Tags: php, sql, substr

I am trying to make a data entry/extraction system for a ticket game.
At any one time there are 24 different tickets with the possibility of around 100 total active tickets.
Each ticket has a barcode which is 16 digits long. The first 4 digits of that barcode are the Game ID.

So far I have managed to pull the data from the sql database and strip the first 4 digits off and assign it to a value but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Here's my code so far.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM TicketInventory WHERE DateStamp='" . $_POST['DateStamp'] . "'");
  echo "<table border=3><tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<td><table><tr><td></td><td>Game ID</td><td>Book Number</td><td>Ticket #</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>01</td>";
  echo "<td><input name=\"GameID1\" size=\"4\" type=\"text\" value=\"", substr($row['Ticket1'], 0, 4), "\" /></td>"; 
  echo "<td><input name=\"BookID1\" size=\"6\" type=\"text\" value=\"", substr($row['Ticket1'], 5, 6), "\" /></td>"; 
  echo "<td><input name=\"TicketNumber1\" size=\"3\" type=\"text\" value=\"", substr($row['Ticket1'], 11, 3), "\" /></td></tr>";
```

I would like to convert GameID1 into the actual ticket name.
Since the GameID1 is generated when the page is loaded I'm guessing I will have to somehow  reference the 100 possible ticket names somewhere in the code???

I am very open to any suggestions on how to accomplish this. Maybe a completely different direction??

Thanks in advance.

Ron

Comment: Are there 100 different games? Or just a few?

Comment: Where are the ticket names stored?

Comment: There are around 100 different games at any one time. We only use 24 per month. Next month we will use 24 different games.

Comment: I have yet to put the ticket names in anywhere. I can make a different sql db with ticket names. But because the GameID is generated once the page is loaded I'm not sure how to pull them out.

Comment: Query the TickeyInventory table, extract the GameID, then insert whatever needs to be inserted into a new table.